# How to connect your network printer via another computer?

Tags: linux, network-printer, cups

My need is a little strange, maybe.

I have a proxy server **A** with IP `210.11.11.1` and a network printer **B** with IP `210.11.11.2` in the same room. I have a computer **C** with IP `202.33.33.1` in another room。C can be connected to **A** directly, and **A** can also reach B directly. But **C** can not reach **B**. What I want is to use the network printer **B** on my computer **C**.

How can I connect the network printer **B** through the computer **A** to my computer **C** in *Ubuntu 16.04*?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: run a print server on A?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any "proxy" server on computer **A**.
Print subsystem provides the ability to print to the printer through an intermediate host.

You need:

1. Install [cups](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkPrintingWithUbuntu) on computer **A**
2. Connect printer **B** to cups on computer **A**
3. Share printer **B** on cups on computer **A**
4. Connect printer **B** shared from cups on computer **A** to computer **C**

Answer (score 0):

You might be blocked by a firewall or having routing issues.

First, fix the routing issue or open the firewall ports. If you can ping each other, you may connect to the shared printer.

There is no proxy when using networked printers.